# You started loading the font "Poppins_400Regular" error

Tags: react-native

i am getting this error mutiple time

You started loading the font "Poppins_400Regular", but used it before it finished loading. You need to wait for Font.loadAsync to complete before using the font.

when run the code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

In your apps entry point, usually `App.jsx` you can render null or a loading state whilst the fonts for your app load, and then once the loadAsync finishes you render your app, something along the lines of:

```js
// App.jsx, or whatever your entry point is
const App = () => {
  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = React.useState(false)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    Font.loadAsync({
      "Poppins_400Regular": require("../path/to/your/font"),
    })
    .then(() => {
     setFontLoaded(true)
    }) 
  }, [])

  if (!fontLoaded) return null

  return (
    // All of your normal app ui
  )
}
```